# Docker-compose, Laravel-echo-server and Redis connectivity issue: [ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.2:6379

Tags: docker, redis, configuration, docker-compose, laravel-echo

I'm setting up a docker stack with PHP, PostgreSQL, Nginx, Laravel-Echo-Server and Redis and having some issues with Redis and the echo-server connecting. I'm using a docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/php/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - app-tier
    ports:
      - 9002:9000
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/app
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - app-tier
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./public:/srv/app/public
  db:
    build:
      context: .docker/postgres/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - app-tier
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      - .docker/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  laravel-echo-server:
    build:
      context: .docker/laravel-echo-server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - app-tier
    ports:
      - 6001:6001
    links:
      - 'redis:redis'
  redis:
    build:
      context: .docker/redis
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - app-tier
    volumes:
      - .docker/redis/data:/var/lib/redis/data
```

My echo-server Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/

RUN apk add --update \
    python \
    python-dev \
    py-pip \
    build-base

RUN npm install

COPY laravel-echo-server.json /usr/src/app/laravel-echo-server.json

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Redis Dockerfile:

```
FROM redis:latest

LABEL maintainer="maintainer"

COPY . /usr/src/app
COPY redis.conf /usr/src/app/redis/redis.conf

VOLUME /data

EXPOSE 6379

CMD ["redis-server", "/usr/src/app/redis/redis.conf"]
```

My laravel-echo-server.json:

```
{
    "authHost": "localhost",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
            "port": "6379",
            "host": "redis"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": ""
}
```

The redis.conf is the default right now. The error I am getting from the laravel-echo-server is:

```
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.0.2:6379 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1163:14)
```

Redis is up and running fine, using the configuration file and ready to accept connections. `docker ps` shows both redis and echo-server are up, so they're just not connecting as the error indicates. If I change the final line in the Redis Dockerfile to just `CMD ["redis-server"]` it appears to connect and auto uses the default config (which is the same as the one I have in my .docker directory), but I get this error: `Possible SECURITY ATTACK detected. It looks like somebody is sending POST or Host: commands to Redis. This is likely due to an attacker attempting to use Cross Protocol Scripting to compromise your Redis instance. Connection aborted.`

Comment: Could it be due to missing port configuration on your compose config -> redis service?
I think there should have ports: - "6379":"6379", on Dockerfile you map which port will your container use inside, but you did not map it externally to your host use, so, your other services won't find it.

Comment: Yeah, I've gone back and forth with that and it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Are you sure you used correct `Dockerfile` for last 3 services?
Looks like `laravel-echo-server`, `redis` and `db` are using same Dockerfile.

Comment: My issue turned out to be in the redis configuration. I was bound to localhost only and when I commented that out it was listening to all connections on the server.